# Cannot uninstall MongoDB

Tags: uninstall, dpkg, mongodb, software-uninstall

It seems that following the official MongoDB installation instructions when installing on Debian direct you to a world of pain.

First, it did not install correctly, so now I am trying to remove all installed MongoDB packages to be able to start from scratch.
But frustratingly, because it (presumably) did not install cleanly, it won't uninstall.

Originally, I installed it using [these instructions](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-debian/).

Currently, I've managed to remove every package apart from `mongodb-org-server` which, just won't go.

An attempted removal results in the following:

```
$ sudo apt-get remove mongodb-org-server
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
mongodb-org-server
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 23.9 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
(Reading database ... 31030 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing mongodb-org-server ...
invoke-rc.d: unknown initscript, /etc/init.d/mongod not found.
dpkg: error processing mongodb-org-server (--remove):
 subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 100
invoke-rc.d: unknown initscript, /etc/init.d/mongod not found.
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 100
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mongodb-org-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Any idea how I can properly and cleanly get rid of MongoDB now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
apt-get --reinstall install mongodb
```

This will pretend that mongodb isn't installed already and overwrite the old files.

Afterwards you should be able to remove it like usual.

Answer (score 1):

Just follow these commands to uninstall mongodb

```
sudo apt-get purge mongodb mongodb-clients mongodb-server mongodb-dev

sudo apt-get purge mongodb-10gen

sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Comment: This generates the same error as reported by the OP.

Answer (score 1):

Uninstall and remove Mongo packages.

```
$ sudo apt-get purge mongodb-org*
```

Check if related directories removed

```
$ sudo rm -r /var/log/mongodb
$ sudo rm -r /var/lib/mongodb
```

Recheck for autoremove any remaining mongo packages

```
$ sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Configure your directory

```
$ sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

Force install anything required

```
$ sudo apt-get install -f
```

Re-install from https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/

Finally restart your Ubuntu and check status of Mogodb server as you did earlier.