# Cannot uninstall mongodb-org-server

Tags: server, apt, mongodb

### Problem

I am trying to get rid of mongodb-org-server once and for all, but this is rather challenging. No matter what I do, I always end up with the same errors:

```
(Reading database ... 74764 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing mongodb-org-server (3.4.1) ...
invoke-rc.d: unknown initscript, /etc/init.d/mongod not found.
dpkg: error processing package mongodb-org-server (--remove):
 subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 100
invoke-rc.d: unknown initscript, /etc/init.d/mongod not found.
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 100
Removing libc-ares2:amd64 (1.10.0-2ubuntu0.1) ...
Removing libv8-3.14.5 (3.14.5.8-5ubuntu2) ...
Removing mongodb-org-mongos (3.4.1) ...
Removing mongodb-org-shell (3.4.1) ...
Removing mongodb-org-tools (3.4.1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.19-0ubuntu6.6) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1ubuntu1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mongodb-org-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

### Research

To solve this, I tried following another solution:

- [Can not uninstall MongoDB](https://askubuntu.com/questions/591220/can-not-uninstall-mongodb)

but to no avail.

### Questions

Any solutions? At this point I am considering a complete format ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to find file `var/lib/dpkg/info/mongodb-org-server.prerm` and comment/remove a line

`invoke-rc.d mongod stop || exit $?`

where stop command is placed.
Then try to get rid of mongodb-org-server again.